# javascript: Different syntax same answer

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="checkbox" id="alert1" value="111">
<input type="checkbox" id="alert2" value="222">
<input type="checkbox" id="alert3" value="333">
<input type="button" onclick="checkBox()" value="check">

function checkBox(){

   var alert1 = document.getElementById('alert1').checked;
   var alert2 = document.getElementById('alert2').checked;
   var alert3 = document.getElementById('alert3').checked;

   if(alert1 == 1 && alert2 == 2 && alert3 == 1){
      do somthing...
   }

   if(alert1 == 1 || alert2 == 2 || alert3 == 1){
      do somthing...
   }
}
```

What should i do if i like only one of this condition to be "true".
This syntax show both of the conditions as "true".

Comment: ? there are 3 conditions

Comment: Are you looking for `else if` ?

Comment: And the second set of expressions will always evaluate as true if the first is true.

Comment: So you want like `alert1 == 1 && alert2 != 2 && alert3 != 1`?

Comment: @JoelEtherton unless do somthing does somthing ...

Comment: Are you looking for an `exclusive or`, that is something that is true when exactly one of its clauses is true but false when more than one of them is true?

Comment: @mcalex: Well since we're picking nits, I guess they won't both evaluate because `do somthing...` isn't valid JavaScript and the script won't compile.

Comment: no, i meant if //do somthing changes alert1 && alert2 && alert3

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

Comment: `unless do somthing does somthing`.... sounds good..

Comment: @Aviway do you mean: if they're all checked, do something, but if at least one is not checked (and at least one is checked) then do something else?

Comment: yes. But the answer of Ergec helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had hard times to understand what you need. Hope this is what you are after

```
function (){
  if(alert1 == 1 && alert2 == 2 && alert3 == 1){
    //do some stuff
  } else if (alert1 == 1 || alert2 == 2 || alert3 == 1){
    //do other stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Think you might be right...

Comment: It's sad we all have to guess...

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood corectly what want... Here you go

```
var onlyOne = (alert1 == 1) + (alert2 == 1) + (alert3 == 1);
if (onlyOne == 1)
{
   // do stuff
}
```